# Calling private functions in nested classes

Tags: c++

I've developed a class, let's call it foo. In the header file, I've opted to have a class containing all of foo's private members in the `private:` section. This way, if I have to edit any private members of foo, I don't have to recompile every source file which uses foo.h. It's set up as such:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class fooData;

class foo
{
   private:
      fooPrivate *prv; // This class stores foo's private members
   public:
      foo(); // Default constructor
      void bar();
}

#endif
```

My foo.cpp class looks like this:

```
#include "foo.h"

class fooPrivate // Class which stores foo's private members
{
   public:
      void doMagic();
}

foo::foo()
{
   prv = new fooPrivate; // Instantiate fooPrivate
   prv->doMagic();
}

void foo::magic() // This is a public member function of foo
{
   std::cout << "Magic!" << std::endl;
}

void fooPrivate::doMagic() // This is a function of private member fooPrivate
{
   magic(); // I want to call a public member of foo here
}
```

Most of you already know the error I'm going to to from attempting to call magic() from doMagic():

```
error: 'magic' was not declared in this scope
```

And, changing the call to foo::magic() results in:

```
error: cannot call member function 'void foo::magic()' without onject
```

Now, I would really like to avoid instantiating an object of type foo, inside an object of type fooPrivate, which itself results from an instantiation of an object of type foo... So, is there a way to call the *public* member function magic() from a public member function of fooPrivate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create fooPrivate, pass in a reference to foo as part of the constructor:

```
foo::foo()
{
  prv= new fooPrivate( * this) ;
}

class fooPrivate
{
  foo & foo_ ;
  ...
}

fooPrivate::fooPrivate( foo & aparen) : foo_( aparen ) { }
```

Then in `doMagic()` just call it by reference:

```
void fooPrivate::doMagic()
{
  foo_.magic() ;
}
```

Also, store fooPrivate in a unique_ptr so that when foo is destroyed, fooPrivate is destroyed along with it:

```
class foo
{
  private:
    std::unique_ptr<fooPrivate> prv ;
```

Which for convenience you could initialize like:

```
foo::foo() : prv( new fooPrivate( * this ) ) { }
```

By the way, I don't recommend calling out to `prv->magic()` inside the constructor if it's then going to call back into the still being created `foo` with the call to `doMagic`.

Comment: Implementing your solution, I ran into "error: class 'fooPrivate' does not have any field named 'foo_'."
Adding a declaration of "foo foo_" into fooPrivate results in successful compilation but segfaults as well during runtime. 
Edit: I may know the cause and will get back to you if not.

Comment: Sorry was going to post that part of the definition, let me edit.

Comment: That fixed it. Great explanation and very neat trick. You may want to further edit your solution to add a closing brace after "foo & foo_;", before the "..." as without it, it appears you're indicating that "fooPrivate::fooPrivate( foo & aparen) : foo_( aparen ) { }" resides within the class definition. No capable coder would mistake what you were indicating, but a novice stumbling upon your solution could become confused.

Comment: I was tempted to check in my test file somewhere (I checked my syntax before posting), but didn't in the end.  Glad you worked out the implementation.